# how to compare text between xml tags using perl

Tags: xml, perl, xml-parsing, perl-module

I have xml data like this

```
 <ce:affiliation id="aff1">
 <ce:label>a</ce:label>
 <ce:textfn>Department of Urology, Radboud University Nijmegen Medical Center, Nijmegen, The Netherlands</ce:textfn>
  <sa:affiliation>
 <sa:organization>Department of Urology</sa:organization>
 <sa:organization>Radboud University Nijmegen Medical Center</sa:organization>
 <sa:city>Nijmegen</sa:city>
 </sa:affiliation>
```

and ect..

nw i want read the text inside the **"sa:affiliation"** while reading text, first read text in tag inside sa:affilliation and make text like "*Department of Urology, Radboud University Nijmegen Medical Center, Nijmegen*" in this "," separation format and compare this text with text which inside **"ce:textn" .... "/ce:textn"**

like is i need to compare each **ce:affillition** tag with **sa:affilliation** for multiple files and if any mismatch need tell to user.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit vague. It is not clear where each fragment of XML goes. One file? several files? One fragment per file? Several? If the data is in several files, how do you link a `ce:affilliation` element with the corresponding `sa:affilliation`, especially if what you are checking is whether the 2 texts match? Why is there no country in `sa:affilliation`? Where are the namespaces declared?

Assuming the 2 pieces of data are in 2 files, and the namespace prefixes do not change:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

use warnings;

use XML::Twig;
use Test::More;

my $DEFAULT_COUNTRY= "The Netherlands";

# usage is <tool> <ce file> <sa file>
my( $ce_file, $sa_file)= @ARGV;

my $ce= XML::Twig->new->parsefile( $ce_file)->root;
my $ce_text = $ce->field( 'ce:textfn');

my $sa= XML::Twig->new->parsefile( $sa_file)->root;

# add the country if not present
if( ! $sa->first_child( 'sa:country')) 
  { $sa->insert_new_elt( last_child => 'sa:country' => $DEFAULT_COUNTRY); }

my $sa_text= join( ', ', $sa->children_text);

is( $ce_text, $sa_text, "checking " . $ce->id);

done_testing();
```

Comment: It is several file and several fragment only . just i want compare both text in ce:affilliaiton and sa:affilliation which contains between tags. In given statement the country is missing in sa:affillion so give some error for that.

Comment: first i want read the text inside sa:affilliation after reading each tag inside the sa:affilliation this my text after reading "Department of Urology, Radboud University Nijmegen Medical Center, Nijmegen" nw compare this text into ce:affilliaiton text .

Comment: as far as I understand, you should be OK then. Remove the part of the code that sets the default country. Since you haven't really answered most of my questions, I guess you don't need any more help then ;--)

Comment: Finally i found this code but is there any method to pickup this ce:affillition and sa:affillition text without using if else condition because it failed some condition.It can possible to done without using use XML::Twig; use Test::More;

Answer (score 1):

You can use [XML::XPath](http://search.cpan.org/~msergeant/XML-XPath-1.13/XPath.pm) to find the nodes you want. Then just check whether the two nodes' `string_value` are `neq`.

Comment: I am new to perl. please can u give full script for this ??

Comment: Maybe you should update your post with what you've tried so far. If you know how to use CPAN, the link I gave you should help you get started without having to write your own XML parser. :)

Answer (score 0):

finally i found this code but is there any method to pickup this ce:affillition and sa:affillition text without using if else condition because it failed some condition.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  
@files = <*.xml>;
open my $out, '>', 'output.xml' or die $!;
foreach $file (@files) {
open   (FILE, "$file");
$a =1;
while(my $line= <FILE> ){
do{
if ($line =~ /<ce:affiliation id=\"aff$a\">(.+?)<ce:textfn>(.+?)<\/ce:textfn><sa:affiliation>(.+?)<\/sa:affiliation><\/ce:affiliation>/){
$count = $3;
$textfn = $2;
print ("$count\n");
print ("$textfn\n");
if ($count =~ /<\/sa:(.+?)>/){
$count =~ s/<\/sa:organization>/, /g;
$count =~ s/<\/sa:city>/, /g;
$count =~ s/<\/sa:country>/, /g;
$count =~ s/<\/sa:state>/, /g;
$count =~ s/<sa:organization>//g;
$count =~ s/<sa:city>//g;
$count =~ s/<sa:country>//g;
$count =~ s/<sa:state>//g;
chop($count);
chop($count);
if($count ne $textfn){
print $out("$file affilliation $a is mismatch\n");}}}
else{
if($line =~ /<ce:affiliation id=\"aff$a\">(.+?)<ce:textfn>(.+?)<\/ce:textfn><\/ce:affiliation>/){
print $out("$file sa:affilliation missing for $a\n");}}
$a=$a+1;}
while($line =~ /aff$a/);}}
```

For this condition xml i am getting wrong result

```
 <ce:affiliation id="aff1"><ce:label>a</ce:label><ce:textfn>Department of Urology, Radboud University Nijmegen Medical Center, Nijmegen, The Netherlands</ce:textfn><sa:affiliation><sa:organization>Department of Urology</sa:organization><sa:organization>Radboud University Nijmegen Medical Center</sa:organization><sa:city>Nijmegen</sa:city><sa:country>The Netherlands</sa:country></sa:affiliation></ce:affiliation><ce:affiliation id="aff2"><ce:textfn>Norris Comprehensive Cancer Center, University of Southern California Institute of Urology, Los Angeles, California</ce:textfn></ce:affiliation><ce:affiliation id="aff3"><ce:label>c</ce:label><ce:textfn>Department of Urology, Stanford University, Stanford, California</ce:textfn><sa:affiliation><sa:organization>Department of Urology</sa:organization><sa:organization>Stanford University</sa:organization><sa:city>Stanford</sa:city><sa:state>California</sa:state></sa:affiliation></ce:affiliation><ce:correspondence id="cor1"></article>
```

Comment: Is this meant to be an answer to your own question, or is it an example of what you've tried so far? If the latter, you should edit your original question and add it there. Also, _please_ indent your code, it makes it _much_ easier to read.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Finally i found this code but is there any method to pickup this ce:affillition and sa:affillition text without using if else condition because it failed some condition.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got required output.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  
@files= <*.xml>;
open my $out, '>', 'output.xml' or die $!;
foreach $file (@files){
open   (FILE, "$file");
my $a =1;
while(my $line= <FILE> ){
do{
if($line =~ /<ce:affiliation id=\"aff$a\">(.+?)<\/ce:affiliation>/){
$count=$1;
if($count =~ /<ce:label>/){
$count=~ s/<ce:label>(.+?)<\/ce:label>//;}
if($count =~ /<sa:affiliation>/){
if($count =~ /<ce:textfn>(.+?)<\/ce:textfn><sa:affiliation>(.+?)<\/sa:affiliation>/){
$textfn=$1;
$sff=$2;
$sff =~ s/<\/sa:organization>/, /g;
$sff =~ s/<\/sa:city>/, /g;
$sff =~ s/<\/sa:country>/, /g;
$sff =~ s/<\/sa:state>/, /g;
$sff =~ s/<sa:organization>//g;
$sff =~ s/<sa:city>//g;
$sff =~ s/<sa:country>//g;
$sff =~ s/<sa:state>//g;
chop($sff);
chop($sff);}
if($textfn ne $sff){
print $out("$file ce:aff and sa:aff  mismatch in aff$a\n");}
if($textfn =~ /<ce:sup>/){
print $out("$file check label aff$a\n");}}
else{
if($line =~ /\"art520.dtd\"/){
print $out("$file strct affilition missing for aff$a\n");
}}}
$a=$a+1;
}while($line =~ /aff$a/);}}
```